# svg - keep fill texture original size when resizing a path

Tags: css, svg, base64, scale, fill

I define a svg `<pattern>` like this:

```
<svg height="10" width="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> 
  <defs> 
    <pattern id="circles-1_4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10"> 
      <image xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" 
        x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">
      </image> 
    </pattern> 
  </defs> 
</svg>
```

visually, this is the equivalent of this:
[image]

So then I call my css for svg as a fill like this:

```
svg #VISUEL-3 * {fill: url(#circles-1);}
```

I get a pretty good result:
[image]

But when I display my graphic smaller (1/4 in this i.e), the fill adapt like this
[image]

It's difficult to see on the screenshots because the scale is broken due to the width 100% of stackoverflow but the vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke works perfectly so the strokes have the same size between the first and the second screenshot and the number "1,2,3,4,5,6" as well.

So as you can see the fill has adapted...

**Is it possible to keep the same pattern size (same size of dots) like in css?** That look messy visually when I have two graphics that are not of the same size and are next to each other.

Is my method right to obtain that? (I'm ready to change my method..)

Comment: As an aside: The `<image>` element in the pattern is making this unneccessarily obscure. Exchange it in its entirety with `<circle cx="1.25" cy="1.25" r="1.25"/>`, and you get the same result.

Comment: =))))) obviously.. I'm not expert in <svg>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern elements are applied to the referencing element *before* transformations on the element or one of its parents are applied - so the pattern size gets transformed as well. The only way to counteract this is to write a seperate pattern element for each scale you us it at, including a `patternTransform` with the inverse scale. Fortunately, there is a mechanism for cloning patterns with a `xlink:href` attribute.

```css
.simple {
    fill: url(#dots);
}
.quarter {
    fill: url(#quadrupleDots);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="150">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="dots" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="10" height="10">
      <circle r="1.25" cx="1.25" cy="1.25" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="quadrupleDots" xlink:href="#dots" patternTransform="scale(4)" />
  </defs>
  <rect id="shape" class="simple" x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" />
  <rect class="quarter" x="800" y="80" width="100" height="100" transform="scale(0.25)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: sorry for the late answer.. For my specific case I had to do some javascript to calculate the exact scale. But your method is the good one.. thanks ! =)